# Render partial view based on condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a few partial views that should render when the user has a certain Role.

Now, I want to avoid doing something like

```
<% if(user is in role){..here goes the html.. }%>
```

I would like to be able to do (at the top of the ascx) :

```
<% this.RenderOnlyForRoles(list of roles) %>
```

Now, in the BasePartialView I have a list of roles that gets populated when RenderOnlyForRoles is called.

The problem is that the RenderOnlyForRoles is called after .. all events I can think of :) and I can't stop the rendering of the control.

Any ideas on how to obtain what I want ?

**EDIT:** Anyone knows if other viewengines might support this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [HTMLHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx)

```
public static void RenderOnlyForRoles(this HtmlHelper html, List<string> roles))
{
    if (check if user in roles)
    {
        html.RenderPartial(yourview);
    }
}
```

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Wanted to post the same. But that's not what he actually tries to achieve. He wants to explicitly delegate checking of roles responsibility to partial view.

Comment: Ah okay, but that logic should be in controller should it not then? Perhaps an attribute for relevant action methods?

Comment: Well... this is a Partial View , so I don't what exactly should I check in the Controller ?. I mean I have a view , with 3 Partial Views. Only one Partial view should be displayed at any time.

Comment: In your controller,I would check which views are to be rendered and send that in the ViewModel or view data. Kindness, Dan

Comment: I would recommend you do the simplest thing that could work - which in this case is to use an HTML helper.  It's code - you can always change it at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to solve this type of challenge by using polymorphism. In this case you could have a base View you want to render.

When the user is in the desired role, you render the concrete View; otherwise, you can render a *Null View* that basically does nothing.

Until ASP.NET MVC 2 you will need to map polymorphic Views by hand, but I [recently wrote a blog post that describes how you can do that](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/07/16/DataTemplatingInASPNETMVC.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I think this is seriously over-engineering the solution.  I would recommend you do the simplest thing that could work in this scenario - which is probably to use an HTML helper.